# .htaccess causes Internal Server Error on wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using Wamp Server for Windows. I have a folder named "tester" in the www directory. Everything works fine until I put my .htaccess file in the "tester" folder. This is my .htaccess file:

```
//Stop hotlinking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/tester/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|cpp|java|c|txt|in|out|exe|o|ico|png)$ localhost/tester/signin.php[R=302,L]

//Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

//Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

After adding the .htaccess file to the "tester" folder, I get an Internal Server Error.

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at wampserver@wampserver.invalid to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `.htaccess`, comments should be commented with `pound sign (#)` instead of `//`.

```
#Stop hotlinking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/tester/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|cpp|java|c|txt|in|out|exe|o|ico|png)$ localhost/tester/signin.php[R=302,L]

#Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

#Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

This works on my local environment.

Comment: There's also online .htaccess validators, such as http://www.htaccesscheck.com/, which show the errors described above.